# How can I create my primary key in Access on a SELECT INTO statement?

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

I have a SQL statement in SQL which selects columns from a table and copies them into a temporary table. It is looking for duplicates. I need to copy this into a temporary table WITH the primary key, but I do not want it to look for duplicates based on the primary key since it is unique. This is what I have so far, is there an easy way to do this? If I had ID to my select/group by then it will just look for duplicates based on the ID criteria (AKA It will never find a duplicate).

```
SELECT DIVISION, FIPS_COUNTY_CODE, LAST, SUFFIX, FIRST, TITLE, BIRTHDATE, count(*) INTO TempDupes
FROM [work]
GROUP BY DIVISION, FIPS_COUNTY_CODE, LAST, SUFFIX, FIRST, TITLE, BIRTHDATE
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the primary key along with the other columns, then you can `JOIN` back to the original table:

```
SELECT w.*
INTO TEMPDUPES
FROM (SELECT DIVISION, FIPS_COUNTY_CODE, LAST, SUFFIX, FIRST, TITLE,   
             BIRTHDATE, count(*) as cnt
      FROM [work]
      GROUP BY DIVISION, FIPS_COUNTY_CODE, LAST, SUFFIX, FIRST, TITLE, BIRTHDATE
      HAVING count(*) > 1
     ) as ww INNER JOIN
     [work] as w
     ON w.division = ww.division AND
        w.FIPS_COUNTY_CODE = ww.FIPS_COUNTY_CODE AND
        . . .
```

For the `SELECT`, you can just join the columns that you need.

Comment: I tried this (with the fields filled in)
but it says "Syntax error in the from clause"

Gist: https://gist.github.com/rohanharrison/27f4895b525b6f2ad392ba886d084d4d

Comment: @rohanharrison . . . The real issue was the `INTO` in the subquery.  If you want a table with that information, then `INTO` needs to be in the outermost query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I tried that but it still didn't work: https://gist.github.com/rohanharrison/db6134fcfb3ffd279e191ebee40264be

Wait I just saw your edit.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It runs, but it does not copy any of the data into the table (0 rows) where there should be roughly 600 in this case.

Comment: There is no `WORK` alias in either derived table. Try `w`.